# How to open a new tab/window on clicking on ItemTemplate asp:Image Button with Query String?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ImageButton inside the DataList ItemTemplate, I am trying to open a new page (new tab) on clicking on ImageButton, but its opening in same tab.

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtmImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>'OnCommand="ibtmImage_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id").ToString() %>' OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';" />
</ItemTemplate>

protected void ibtmImage_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("ItemList.aspx?Id=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

How to open a page in new tab/new window.

Some one please help me.

Comment: I don't want to use any extra control like hyperlink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am doing something like this and its opening in new tab

```
protected void ibtmImage_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
     string strJS = ("<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('ItemList.aspx?Id=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + "','_blank');</script>");
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "strJSAlert", strJS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your aspx page against OnClientClick do:

```
OnClientClick="window.open('http://yourpagetopen/');"
```

So your image button would be:

```
<asp:ImageButton 
 ID="ibtmImage" 
 runat="server" 
 ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>'
 OnCommand="ibtmImage_Command" 
 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id").ToString() %>' 
 OnClientClick="window.open('aspnetForm'); " />
```

Also you may get rid of `Response.Redirect` in the server side event and pass the argument from the onClientClick.

Answer (score 0):

**ASPX**

```
   <asp:TemplateField Headertext="Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>           
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CssClass="no_underline"
                                NavigateUrl='<%# GetNavigateUrl(Eval("Id").ToString()) %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**CS**
Bind next function

```
   protected string GetNavigateUrl(string Id)
        {
            string startDateStr = StartDate.ToShortDateString();
            string endDateStr = EndDate.ToShortDateString();
            var script = String.Format("javascript:var w=window.showModalDialog('Details.aspx?Id={0}&StartDate={1}&EndDate={2}', " +
                                 "'Details', 'dialogWidth:1120px; dialogHeight:500px; resizable:no; status: no;');", PartnerId, startDateStr, endDateStr);           
            return script;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="docTitle" Text='<%#Eval("Titleofdoc") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# string.Concat("~/UI/UploadFilestest.aspx?docId=", Eval("DocId"))%>' Target="_blank"
                                runat="server" />
```

Comment: This answer doesn't use an image button